# How to write search(list) queries in Mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

There is a search page in webapplication(Pagination is used : 10 records per page). Database used : Mysql. Table has around 1000 00records.Query is tuned as in query is using index (checked Explain plan).Result set that fetches around 17000 rows and takes around 5 sec .Can any please suggest how to optimize search Query.(Note : Tried to use limit but query time did not improve).
Query Eg:

```
Select * from abc 
Join def on abc.id=def.id 
where date >= '2013-09-03' 
and date <='2014-10-01'  
and def.state=1
```

-- id on both table is indexed 
-- date and state column cannot be indexed as they have low SI.

Comment: You need indexes on both `date` and `state` and not sure why they can not be indexed. You are using where condition and without indexed column you are likely to have this slow nature.

Comment: state is like a flag which has values like 0 and 1 . Hence cannot be indexed.selectivity index on date is less than 10 %

Comment: If indexing isn't very selective, then the only way to implement the query is with a full scan. That has to read all the records, so it will be slow.